# Can't seem to access the Add Constraints (With Targets) menu

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm sure this must be a very basic mistake I've made, but I really can't seem to find the "Add Constraints (With Targets)" menu. I'm in Pose Mode with my armature, and I'm using armature layers. I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the Viewport and I've checked that this was mapped correctly in my hotkeys. It is, but nothing shows up when I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + select two armature bones and try to access this menu.

I'm trying to copy the transform for a ctrl FK bone to a deformation bone, and I've even tried to go to *Bone > Add Bone Constraints > Copy Transform*, but when I try to go through this method, I can't seem to target my FK bone at all with the eyedropper...

Comment: the eyedropper will select the armature, not the bone, you need to select the bone afterwards by typing it or selecting it in the dropdown list